# How i can handle Spring boot main thread to wait until the new thread is doing some calculation

Tags: multithreading

I have a scenario in which i have to stop the main thread until the execution of second thread.

```
@PostMapping("/filter")
public ResponseEntity<?> filter(@Valid @RequestBody R1 r1) throws InterruptedException {

    Double lat = (r1.getLat());
    Double lang = r1.getLongi();

    List<LatLang> list2 =latlangRepo.findAllWithin(lang,lat);   

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        Double lat1 = list2.get(i).getLat();
        Double longi1 = list2.get(i).getLang();

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                  //Some logic to calculate
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you starting another thread? If you just run the code in series will it perform how you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the computation in a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) and then wait for the future to complete. I have put the sample below based on your code, you may have to make a few changes to make it work, but you will get the general idea

```
@PostMapping("/filter")
public ResponseEntity<?> filter(@Valid @RequestBody R1 r1) throws InterruptedException {

    Double lat = (r1.getLat());
    Double lang = r1.getLongi();

    List<LatLang> list2 =latlangRepo.findAllWithin(lang,lat);   

    List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        Double lat1 = list2.get(i).getLat();
        Double longi1 = list2.get(i).getLang();

        //Delegate to the thread asynchronously 
        Future<String> completableFuture = calculateAsync();
        futures.add(completableFuture);
    }
    //Wait for the completion of all the futures and collact result
    String combined = futures.stream().
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}

public Future<String> calculateAsync(Double lat, Double long) throws InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture 
      = new CompletableFuture<>();

    Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
        //Your computation here
        completableFuture.complete("Result of your computation");
    });

    return completableFuture;
}
```

See more examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture)